# various problem in install ubuntu studio

Tags: system-installation, sound, graphics, display, configuration

### I have a old PC. I would like to use for make Music and some video. Nothing of professional. Just for fun.
With Win 7 I have some problems for make video. **Too low FPS rate.** I would check if is it possible to use Linux or if the hardware it's too old. (about 8 years) and so if I need to change with a Main board more new and more powerful.

My device is that:
gigabyte GA-MA74GM-S2H
AMD Athlon(tm) X2 245 Processor"
4 gb ram ddr2 (2x2) but i see only 3gb (in win7 too)
Why?
2 Hd, one of these A SSD Sandisk 120Gb
A cheap web cam: Silicon Motion, Inc. - Taiwan (formerly Feiya Technology Corp.) SM731 Camera"  Vendor: usb 0x090c "
Device: usb 0x71b3 "SM731 Camera"
(But I have others, maybe better)

video card internal:
Model: "ATI RS740 [Radeon 2100]"
Vendor: pci 0x1002 "ATI Technologies Inc"
Device: pci 0x796e "RS740 [Radeon 2100]"
SubVendor: pci 0x1458 "Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd"
SubDevice: pci 0xd000
Driver: "radeon"
Driver Modules: "radeon"
Memory Range: 0xd8000000-0xdfffffff (ro,non-prefetchable)
Memory Range: 0xfdfe0000-0xfdfeffff (rw,non-prefetchable)
I/O Ports: 0xee00-0xeeff (rw)
Memory Range: 0xfde00000-0xfdefffff (rw,non-prefetchable)
Memory Range: 0x000c0000-0x000dffff (rw,non-prefetchable,disabled)
IRQ: 18 (216148 events)
I/O Port: 0x00 (rw)
Module Alias: "pci:v00001002d0000796Esv00001458sd0000D000bc03sc00i00"
Driver Info #0:
Driver Status: radeon is active
Driver Activation Cmd: "modprobe radeon"
Config Status: cfg=new, avail=yes, need=no, active=unknown

But I have others graphic card, if need I can add, if that is a issue.

Internal Audio:

Hardware Class: sound
Model: "ATI SBx00 Azalia (Intel HDA)"
Vendor: pci 0x1002 "ATI Technologies Inc"
Device: pci 0x4383 "SBx00 Azalia (Intel HDA)"
SubDevice: pci 0xa002
Driver: "snd_hda_intel"
Driver Modules: "snd_hda_intel"

and external USB audio Behringer UPhoria  UM2

---

I have tried other linux (example AVlinux and KXlinux) and I have big different problem. Example for WiFi.
I have tried these day ubuntu studio and I have three problem:

1. Why I see only 3Gb of ram and not 4gb?
   This is indeed a minor issue. Just for curiosity.
   but this is not important.
2. If I start without external usb audio card the sound of internal card it's ok. But I would like use the internal card only for output. For input I would like to use the external usb card. But when I connect the usb of external card the internal card stop to work. If I start with the external card connect, the external card works as input, but I cannot use the internal card. How I can do it?
   I check some link but I cannot figure out.
3. If I start a program for webcam, example Guvvcview, I have a low fps (1.39fps),
   I know was low in Win7 too, so I think it's a hardware issue, but there is something I can do for increase this value? Example, if I add a graphic card I able to have a bigger value? there is something else I can do, or only change main board?

If need some information additional, just ask.
If somebody may help in somehow, thanks in advance.

I have 3 problems:

Comment: You've mentioned a number of OSes, this site supports of Ubuntu and flavors of Ubuntu (AVlinux and KXlinux are off-topic, at SE *Unix and Linux* all can be on-topic), and for Ubuntu Studio you didn't provide your release, software stack details so we can't know if that's an issue or not (Ubuntu releases are easy as they used *year.month* format so you know the age of the stack and thus kernel in use). Overall though you're asking 3 questions and not the 1 this site intends.

Comment: OK. may I mistake, I said too much, the ubuntu studio version is the last 20.4 Just one problem. How may fix the audio issue with the external usb audio? I would like to use in Output the internal and in Input the external. May be I must to edit the file alsa base.conf?

Comment: I don know how put the "software stack details "

Comment: 20.04 provides that detail, ie. 2020-April release

Comment: "20.04 provides that detail, ie. 2020-April release" I don' understand (My english is indeed not very good) What means that?

Comment: You provided your stack details, Ubuntu 20.04 LTS means the 2020-April release (Ubuntu releases use a *year.month* format, so 20=2020, and 04=April.  Your software stack was built (compiled etc) for that release

Comment: I see with this command "dmesg" that I have  many error.

Answer (score 0):

Now I add that file if can help,

etc/modprobe/als-base-conf

## autoloader aliases

install sound-slot-0 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-0
install sound-slot-1 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-1
install sound-slot-2 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-2
install sound-slot-3 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-3
install sound-slot-4 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-4
install sound-slot-5 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-5
install sound-slot-6 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-6
install sound-slot-7 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-7

## Cause optional modules to be loaded above generic modules

install snd /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-ioctl32 ; /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-seq ; }

## Workaround at bug #499695 (reverted in Ubuntu see LP #319505)

install snd-pcm /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd-pcm $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-pcm-oss ; : ; }
install snd-mixer /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd-mixer $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-mixer-oss ; : ; }
install snd-seq /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd-seq $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-seq-midi ; /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-seq-oss ; : ; }

install snd-rawmidi /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd-rawmidi $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-seq-midi ; : ; }

## Cause optional modules to be loaded above sound card driver modules

install snd-emu10k1 /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd-emu10k1 $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-emu10k1-synth ; }
install snd-via82xx /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd-via82xx $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-seq ; }

## Load saa7134-alsa instead of saa7134 (which gets dragged in by it anyway)

install saa7134 /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install saa7134 $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist saa7134-alsa ; : ; }

## Prevent abnormal drivers from grabbing index 0

options bt87x index=-2
options cx88_alsa index=-2
options saa7134-alsa index=-2
options snd-atiixp-modem index=-2
options snd-intel8x0m index=-2
options snd-via82xx-modem index=-2
options snd-usb-audio index=-2
options snd-usb-caiaq index=-2
options snd-usb-ua101 index=-2
options snd-usb-us122l index=-2
options snd-usb-usx2y index=-2

## Ubuntu #62691, enable MPU for snd-cmipci

options snd-cmipci mpu_port=0x330 fm_port=0x388

## Keep snd-pcsp from being loaded as first soundcard

options snd-pcsp index=-2

## Keep snd-usb-audio from beeing loaded as first soundcard

options snd-usb-audio index=-2

Answer (score 0):

lsusb -t
/:  Bus 07.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=ohci-pci/2p, 12M
/:  Bus 06.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=ohci-pci/3p, 12M
/:  Bus 05.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=ohci-pci/3p, 12M
/:  Bus 04.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=ohci-pci/3p, 12M
|__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Audio, Driver=snd-usb-audio, 12M
|__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 1, Class=Audio, Driver=snd-usb-audio, 12M
|__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 2, Class=Audio, Driver=snd-usb-audio, 12M
|__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 3, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
/:  Bus 03.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=ohci-pci/3p, 12M
|__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 1.5M
|__ Port 2: Dev 3, If 0, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 1.5M
|__ Port 3: Dev 4, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/4p, 12M
|__ Port 1: Dev 5, If 0, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 12M
|__ Port 1: Dev 5, If 1, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 12M
/:  Bus 02.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=ehci-pci/6p, 480M
/:  Bus 01.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=ehci-pci/6p, 480M
|__ Port 6: Dev 5, If 0, Class=Vendor Specific Class, Driver=rtl8192cu, 480M

dmesg -l err
[    0.245425] ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, While resolving a named reference package element - LNKC (20190816/dspkginit-438)
[    0.245431] ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, While resolving a named reference package element - LNKD (20190816/dspkginit-438)
[    0.245435] ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, While resolving a named reference package element - LNKA (20190816/dspkginit-438)
[    0.245439] ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, While resolving a named reference package element - LNKB (20190816/dspkginit-438)
[    0.245449] ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, While resolving a named reference package element - LNKD (20190816/dspkginit-438)
[    0.245452] ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, While resolving a named reference package element - LNKA (20190816/dspkginit-438)
[    0.245455] ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, While resolving a named reference package element - LNKB (20190816/dspkginit-438)
[    0.245459] ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, While resolving a named reference package element - LNKC (20190816/dspkginit-438)
[    0.245469] ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, While resolving a named reference package element - LNKA (20190816/dspkginit-438)
[    0.245472] ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, While resolving a named reference package element - LNKB (20190816/dspkginit-438)
[    0.245476] ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, While resolving a named reference package element - LNKC (20190816/dspkginit-438)
[    0.245479] ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, While resolving a named reference package element - LNKD (20190816/dspkginit-438)
[    0.245489] ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, While resolving a named reference package element - LNKB (20190816/dspkginit-438)
[    0.245493] ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, While resolving a named reference package element - LNKC (20190816/dspkginit-438)
[    0.245496] ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, While resolving a named reference package element - LNKD (20190816/dspkginit-438)
[    0.245499] ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, While resolving a named reference package element - LNKA (20190816/dspkginit-438)
[    0.245510] ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, While resolving a named reference package element - LNKC (20190816/dspkginit-438)
[    0.245513] ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, While resolving a named reference package element - LNKD (20190816/dspkginit-438)
[    0.245516] ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, While resolving a named reference package element - LNKA (20190816/dspkginit-438)
[    0.245520] ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, While resolving a named reference package element - LNKB (20190816/dspkginit-438)
[    0.245530] ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, While resolving a named reference package element - LNKD (20190816/dspkginit-438)
[    0.245533] ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, While resolving a named reference package element - LNKA (20190816/dspkginit-438)
[    0.245537] ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, While resolving a named reference package element - LNKB (20190816/dspkginit-438)
[    0.245540] ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, While resolving a named reference package element - LNKC (20190816/dspkginit-438)
[    0.245550] ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, While resolving a named reference package element - LNKA (20190816/dspkginit-438)
[    0.245558] ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, While resolving a named reference package element - LNKB (20190816/dspkginit-438)
[    0.245562] ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, While resolving a named reference package element - LNKC (20190816/dspkginit-438)
[    0.245565] ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, While resolving a named reference package element - LNKD (20190816/dspkginit-438)
[    1.553405] ata2: softreset failed (device not ready)
[    1.561408] ata4: softreset failed (device not ready)
[    3.362396] usb 3-3.4: device descriptor read/64, error -62
[    3.537396] usb 3-3.4: device descriptor read/64, error -62
[    3.783395] usb 3-3.4: device descriptor read/64, error -62
[    3.961360] usb 3-3.4: device descriptor read/64, error -62
[    5.065370] usb 3-3.4: device not accepting address 8, error -62
[    5.545357] usb 3-3.4: device not accepting address 9, error -62
[    5.545700] usb 3-3-port4: unable to enumerate USB device
[   16.069363] snd_hda_intel 0000:01:05.2: No response from codec, resetting bus: last cmd=0x000f0000
[   17.071386] snd_hda_intel 0000:01:05.2: azx_get_response timeout, switching to single_cmd mode: last cmd=0x000f0000
[   24.350376] usb 3-3.4: device descriptor read/64, error -62
[   24.529364] usb 3-3.4: device descriptor read/64, error -62
[   24.775390] usb 3-3.4: device descriptor read/64, error -62
[   24.955728] usb 3-3.4: device descriptor read/64, error -62
[   26.057398] usb 3-3.4: device not accepting address 12, error -62
[   26.537364] usb 3-3.4: device not accepting address 13, error -62
[   26.537788] usb 3-3-port4: unable to enumerate USB device
[ 9385.413940] usb 3-3.4: device descriptor read/64, error -62
[ 9385.589631] usb 3-3.4: device descriptor read/64, error -62
[ 9385.833182] usb 3-3.4: device descriptor read/64, error -62
[ 9386.012870] usb 3-3.4: device descriptor read/64, error -62
[ 9387.115132] usb 3-3.4: device not accepting address 16, error -62
[ 9387.594425] usb 3-3.4: device not accepting address 17, error -62
[ 9387.595463] usb 3-3-port4: unable to enumerate USB device